# Объединение таблиц и вставка своих значений

Tags: mysql

Как сделать, чтоб при объединении таблиц, если во второй таблице нет значения, можно было бы подставлять своё значение например 0, иначе 1, чтоб не терялись строки? Если в таблице `user_answers` нет такого `id`, как в таблице `answer_options`, то строки не показываются:

```
SELECT ao.text, ao.result, ao.question_id, ao.id,**(IF( EXISTS(SELECT 
users_answers.answer_id FROM users_answers WHERE 
users_answers.answer_id=ao.id) , 1, 0 )) AS user_result**, ua.text_answer AS 
user_text FROM answer_options ao JOIN questions q1 ON ao.question_id = q1.id 
JOIN quizs q ON q1.quiz_id = q.id JOIN users_answers ua ON ao.id = 
ua.answer_id WHERE q.id=73 AND q.user_id=14
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Вместо JOIN использовал LEFT JOIN